# Como alterar configurações de um binding Source?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net

Como faço para rodar uma aplicação que está fazendo vinculação (binding) num banco de dados local para usar o *binding* em qualquer máquina.

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes do problema? O que você já fez? Especificamente onde está tendo problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os projetos em C# normalmente armazenam as strings de conexões dentro de um arquivo `.config` presente na raiz da aplicação. Normalmente, é só questão de colocar uma string de conexão que faça referência a uma máquina externa, ao invés da máquina local.

Se for um projeto web, o arquivo é o `web.config` se for desktop é o `app.config`.

A pergunta não me ficou muito clara... mas se não for isso me diga através dos comentáros.

Comment: Sim Sim, estava verificando e achei esta configuração mas fiz a aplicação local ela funcionou e testei em uma outra máquina e ela deu incompatibilidade falando que não existia banco correspondente com o banco delimitado na aplicação. O Estranho é que as configurações são as mesmas. Será que em algum local do BindingSource ele pega o nome da máquina(o endereço local do banco) ou ele pega somente o IP local(127.0.0.1)...

Comment: @Fernando Se a conexão usada for local, possivelmente na string de conexão terá algo escrito localhost, em algum ponto.